# UITabBarController pushed down during phone call or Personal hotspot?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out why this happens in my app. Like the image shows, my app gets pushed down off screen instead of resizing properly to accommodate the size change created by a phone call or personal hotspot event...

[image]

So, my app has a storyboard, in the storyboard I simply have a TabBarController pointing to 4 other view controllers.

Any idea why this is happening? How can I fix this so the the app doesn't go off screen at the bottom?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, but I have container view controller with tabbarcontroller as child view controller. I fixed this by adding constraints: (I use Cartography)

```
    constrain(tabBarController.view, containerView) { (tabBarControllerView, containerView) in
        tabBarControllerView.height == containerView.height
        tabBarControllerView.width == containerView.width
    }
```

If you add tabbarcontroller as initialViewController (rootViewController) everything should be OK